# Magento Credit Card Payment method form not showing up in one page checkout on radio button click

Tags: jquery, magento

My website http://bronnrocks.co.za/ onepagecheckout credit card method is not working. When I choose Credit Card(save) the cc form is not loading. Paygate at the backend is also enabled. EFT is working fine. But issue is with cc form not showing up. I checked in firefox and chrome, in both a single error in console is "Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined".Please Help me.

Comment: Do you see errors in the Chrome or Firefox console? Which browser are you testing with? Is it the same behavior with all browsers or specific browsers?

Comment: Yes I checked in firefox and chrome, in both a single error in console is "Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined". Is it related to this?

Comment: It could be. Please edit and add comment information in your question as it is pertinent to your question. Please also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I edited my ques. Thanks. Can you help me out please ?